# Theme based Google play icons

Tags: android, icons

I found that some apps icons on google play are changing their background colour based on whether dark theme is enabled or not like in the photos below.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Light mode icon

[image: Light mode icon]

Dark mode icon

[image: Dark mode icon]

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a transparent background you can define making your app icon.
Probably you remember you need to set a `foreground` (often the symbol, here the pocket) and also a `background`. If you use a transparent background, it will get a greyish black in darkmode and a white in light mode ("whitemode").
It's an optical illusion.

You could check it if you would have the app and set a custom screen wallpaper on your phone, for example with particles. Those would shine through the app icon background.

Probably your idea is posible in the future, I haven't heard about it yet. Cheers!